# Console app crashes when I create an array larger than 37

Tags: c#, arrays

My code creating a Blackjack game:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Crappy_Card_Game
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string ans = null;
        public static string randomans = null;
        public static int card_value;
        public static string[] Deck = new string[37];
        public static int[] Deck_value = new int[37];
        public static string[] Player_Hand = new string[10];
        public static int[] Player_HandValue = new int[10];
        public static string[] Dealer_Hand = new string[10];
        public static int[] Dealer_HandValue = new int[10];
        public static int playerhandvalue;
        public static int dealerhandvalue;
        public static int deckvalue;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int GamesPlayed = 0;
            string again = null;
            do
            {
                ShuffleCards();
                DealingCards();
                PlayersTurn();
                DealersTurn();
                Console.WriteLine();
                if (dealerhandvalue > playerhandvalue && dealerhandvalue <= 21)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Dealer Wins!");
                }
                else if (dealerhandvalue == playerhandvalue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Draw!");
                }
                else if (playerhandvalue <= 21 && playerhandvalue > dealerhandvalue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player Wins!");
                }
                else if (playerhandvalue > 21 && dealerhandvalue < 21)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Dealer Wins!");
                }
                else if (playerhandvalue < 22 && dealerhandvalue > 21)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player Wins!");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like another game? (yes/no)");
                again = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                Console.Clear();
                GamesPlayed++;
                ClearAllArrays(); // Apart from Deck and DeckValue
                if (GamesPlayed == 9 || GamesPlayed > 9)
                {
                    Array.Clear(Deck, 0, Deck.Length);
                    Array.Clear(Deck_value, 0, Deck_value.Length);
                }

            } while (again == "yes");


        }




        static void Playing_Cards()
        {
            card_value = 0;

            switch (randomans)
            {
                case "Ace":
                    card_value = 13;
                    break;
                case "1":
                    card_value = 1;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    card_value = 2;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    card_value = 3;
                    break;
                case "4":
                    card_value = 4;
                    break;
                case "5":
                    card_value = 5;
                    break;
                case "6":
                    card_value = 6;
                    break;
                case "7":
                    card_value = 7;
                    break;
                case "8":
                    card_value = 8;
                    break;
                case "9":
                    card_value = 9;
                    break;
                case "Jack":
                    card_value = 10;
                    break;
                case "Queen":
                    card_value = 11;
                    break;
                case "King":
                    card_value = 12;
                    break;

            }

        }

        static void Picking()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int PickNumber = rnd.Next(0, 12);
            string[] Card_Inventory = new string[13];
            string[] Card_Suit = new string[4];
            Card_Inventory[0] = "Ace";
            Card_Inventory[1] = "1";
            Card_Inventory[2] = "2";
            Card_Inventory[3] = "3";
            Card_Inventory[4] = "4";
            Card_Inventory[5] = "5";
            Card_Inventory[6] = "6";
            Card_Inventory[7] = "7";
            Card_Inventory[8] = "8";
            Card_Inventory[9] = "9";
            Card_Inventory[10] = "Jack";
            Card_Inventory[11] = "Queen";
            Card_Inventory[12] = "King";
            string PickNumberName = Card_Inventory[PickNumber];
            int PickSuit = rnd.Next(0, 3);
            Card_Suit[1] = "Heart";
            Card_Suit[2] = "Spade";
            Card_Suit[3] = "Diamond";
            Card_Suit[0] = "Club";
            string PickSuitName = Card_Suit[PickSuit];
            ans = PickNumberName + " " + PickSuitName;
            randomans = PickNumberName;
        }

        static void ShuffleCards()
        {
            int check = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 37)
            {
                Picking();
                Playing_Cards();
                while (check < 37)
                {
                    if (ans == Deck[check])
                    {
                        Picking();
                        Playing_Cards();
                        check = 0;
                    }
                    check++;
                }
                check = 0;
                Deck[i] = ans;
                Deck_value[i] = card_value;
                i++;
            }
        }

        static void ShowDeck()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < Deck.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Deck[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue..");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void DealingCards()
        {
            int i = 1;
            do
            {
                deckvalue = i;
                i++;
            } while (Deck[i] == null);
            Player_Hand[0] = Deck[deckvalue];
            Player_HandValue[0] = Deck_value[deckvalue];
            Deck[deckvalue] = null;
            Deck_value[deckvalue] = 0;
            deckvalue++;
            Player_Hand[1] = Deck[deckvalue];
            Player_HandValue[1] = Deck_value[deckvalue];
            Deck[deckvalue] = null;
            Deck_value[deckvalue] = 0;
            deckvalue++;
            Dealer_Hand[0] = Deck[deckvalue];
            Dealer_HandValue[0] = Deck_value[deckvalue];
            Deck[deckvalue] = null;
            Deck_value[deckvalue] = 0;
            deckvalue++;
            Dealer_Hand[1] = Deck[deckvalue];
            Dealer_HandValue[1] = Deck_value[deckvalue];
            Deck[deckvalue] = null;
            Deck_value[deckvalue] = 0;
            deckvalue++;

            Console.WriteLine("Dealers Hand: " + Dealer_Hand[0] + " (" + Dealer_HandValue[0] + ") , ? (?) Total: " + Dealer_HandValue[0]);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Your Cards: " + Player_Hand[0] + " (" + Player_HandValue[0] + ") , " + Player_Hand[1] + " (" + Player_HandValue[1] + ") Total:" + (Player_HandValue[0] + Player_HandValue[1]));

        }

        static void PlayersTurn()
        {
            int playervalue = 2;
            playerhandvalue = 0;
            bool round = true;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Hit or Stand?");
                string answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                switch (answer)
                {
                    case "hit":
                        Player_Hand[playervalue] = Deck[deckvalue];
                        Player_HandValue[playervalue] = Deck_value[deckvalue];
                        Deck[deckvalue] = null;
                        Deck_value[deckvalue] = 0;
                        deckvalue++;
                        playervalue++;
                        playerhandvalue = 0;
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Dealers Hand: " + Dealer_Hand[0] + " (" + Dealer_HandValue[0] + ") , ? (?) Total: " + Dealer_HandValue[0]);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Your Hand");
                        for (int i = 0; i < Player_Hand.Length && Player_Hand[i] != null; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(Player_Hand[i] + " ");
                            Console.Write("(" + Player_HandValue[i] + ") , ");
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < Player_HandValue.Length; i++)
                        {
                            playerhandvalue += Player_HandValue[i];
                        }
                        if (playerhandvalue > 21)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Total:" + playerhandvalue + " BUST!");
                            round = false;
                        }
                        else if (playerhandvalue == 21)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Total:" + playerhandvalue + " BLACKJACK!");
                            round = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("Total: " + playerhandvalue);
                        }
                        break;

                    case "stand":
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Dealers Hand: " + Dealer_Hand[0] + " (" + Dealer_HandValue[0] + ") , ? (?) Total: " + Dealer_HandValue[0]);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Your hand: ");
                        playerhandvalue = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < Player_Hand.Length; i++)
                        {
                            playerhandvalue += Player_HandValue[i];
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < Player_Hand.Length && Player_Hand[i] != null; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(Player_Hand[i] + " ");
                            Console.Write("(" + Player_HandValue[i] + ") , ");
                        }
                        if (playerhandvalue > 21)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Total:" + playerhandvalue + " BUST!");
                            round = false;
                        }
                        else if (playerhandvalue == 21)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Total:" + playerhandvalue + "BLACKJACK!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("Total:" + playerhandvalue);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        round = false;
                        break;
                }

            } while (round == true);
        }

        static void DealersTurn()
        {
            int daelervalue = 2;
            bool round = true;
            string result = null;
            dealerhandvalue = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < Dealer_HandValue.Length; i++)
            {
                dealerhandvalue += Dealer_HandValue[i];
            }
            do
            {
                if (dealerhandvalue < playerhandvalue && playerhandvalue <= 21)
                {
                    result = "hit";
                }
                else if (dealerhandvalue == playerhandvalue && dealerhandvalue < 16)
                {
                    result = "hit";
                }
                else if (dealerhandvalue > 21)
                {
                    result = "stand";
                }
                else if (playerhandvalue > 21)
                {
                    result = "stand";
                }
                else if (dealerhandvalue > playerhandvalue)
                {
                    result = "stand";
                }
                switch (result)
                {
                    case "hit":
                        Dealer_Hand[daelervalue] = Deck[deckvalue];
                        Dealer_HandValue[daelervalue] = Deck_value[deckvalue];
                        Deck[deckvalue] = null;
                        Deck_value[deckvalue] = 0;
                        daelervalue++;
                        deckvalue++;
                        dealerhandvalue = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < Dealer_HandValue.Length && Dealer_HandValue[i] != 0; i++)
                        {
                            dealerhandvalue += Dealer_HandValue[i];
                        }
                        break;

                    case "stand":
                        Task.Delay(2000);
                        dealerhandvalue = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < Dealer_HandValue.Length; i++)
                        {
                            dealerhandvalue += Dealer_HandValue[i];
                        }
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Your Hand");
                        for (int i = 0; i < Player_Hand.Length && Player_Hand[i] != null; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(Player_Hand[i] + " ");
                            Console.Write("(" + Player_HandValue[i] + ") , ");
                        }
                        Console.Write(" Toatl " + playerhandvalue);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.Write("Dealers Hand: ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < Dealer_Hand.Length && Dealer_Hand[i] != null; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(Dealer_Hand[i] + " ");
                            Console.Write("(" + Dealer_HandValue[i] + ") , ");
                        }
                        if (dealerhandvalue > 21)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Total:" + dealerhandvalue + " BUST!");
                        }
                        else if (dealerhandvalue == 21)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Total:" + dealerhandvalue + " BLACKJACK!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Total:" + dealerhandvalue);
                        }
                        round = false;
                        break;

                }

            } while (round == true);
        }

        static void ClearAllArrays()
        {
            Array.Clear(Player_Hand, 0, Player_Hand.Length);
            Array.Clear(Dealer_Hand, 0, Dealer_Hand.Length);
            Array.Clear(Dealer_HandValue, 0, Dealer_HandValue.Length);
        }

    }

}
```

The problem is within Shuffle Cards, when I increase the size of the array Deck and Deck_Value to above 37. Also, checking that no cards have been picked more than once, the console seems to crash and not proceed through the code.
Would love some help with this, thanks.

Comment: You cannot pick/create cards like that and be realistic. First use ***one*** random instance for the whole game.  Then, random does not mean unique; there is nothing there from preventing the Jack of Hearts from coming up more than once.  Mimic the real world: create a deck of 52 cards and use them up (preferably with classes)

Comment: What is the message that you receive when it crashes?

Comment: @Plutonix, are you saying that I should randomly choose cards from a pre-existing deck rather than randomly creating cards until I find one that isnt one that I have already chosen.

Comment: @O'Rooney what happens is the console stops going through the code and remains idle as if it was compiling code when it is actually doing nothing at all.

Comment: You should also know that you are never creating Kings with that code.  There is an actual Shuffle algorithm with many examples of it here.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger and seeing where it is getting stuck in the code?

Comment: @O'Rooney The code seems to get stuck at the second if statement

Comment: @O'Rooney I think the problem is the way I have made the program choose a card. Instead of making the program choose a card from a deck of cards which exsits it randomly creates a card and adds it to a deck. The problem is that when the deck starts to get full at around 37 their are very few unique cards to choose meaning that the program has to randomly guess until it finds one of these cards.

Comment: @O'Rooney thanks for your help but sadly it was just a very poorly designed part of my program which I could'nt wrap my head around.